# Calculating a relative offset, given two different endpoint measurements and a midpoint target value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a packetized binary data file that can be referenced in one of two ways:

1. By an arbitrary time tick counter, and
2. By a file offset in bytes.

In my example file, I have the following packet locations:

```
ticks           file offset
729047097              3214   <-- Location of first packet
739047132          37492760   <-- Location of last packet
---------          --------
 10000035          37494046   <-- Differences
```

I need a function that I can present start and end ticks, start and end offsets, and a candidate number of ticks between the start and end ticks, and have it return the corresponding file offset.

I already know that I can compute a *Bytes per Tick* value, and then multiply that by (candidate ticks minus start ticks), but what I would like to know is:

1. What is the general form of this function, and
2. Is there a name for this general form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, it's called linear interpolation, and the formula for it is

$$o(t)=o_0+(t-t_0)\frac{o_1-o_0}{t_1-t_0}\;,$$

where $o_0$, $o_1$ and $t_0$, $t_1$ are the file offsets and ticks at start and end, respectively, and $o(t)$ is the file offset corresponding to tick $t$. The "bytes per tick" value is the fraction on the right. How to arrive at this is explained in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

Comment: Yes! I knew there was a name for it, I just couldn't remember.